# Referring to the element that caused the event from its event handler

Tags: jquery

Today I'm using this code.

```
$("#textBox").on("keyup", function () {
  //if (this.val().length > 4);
  if ($("#textBox").val().length > 4)
    console.log("TextBox written to.");
});
```

However, I it bothers me a bit that I'm using a hard coded reference to the id of the text box. I'd prefer to refer to it as "whomever this event handler has been invoked by". Of course *this* didn't work (my guess is that it refers to the function itself or something like that.

1. How do I refer to "whomever..."?
2. What is *this* referring to there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'this' as selector :

```
$("#textBox").on("keyup", function () {
  if ($(this).val().length > 4)
    console.log("TextBox written to.");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `$(this)` should work. jQuery guarantees that `this` will be a reference to the object acted upon.

However, `this` in your case is the DOMNode. You need to wrap it in a jQuery object to be able to access the jQuery specific function `val`. You could do either `$(this).val()` or `this.value`.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for sure:

```
if (this.value.length > 4)
```

`this` refers here to the DOM element which handler is attached on. The anonymous callback function creates the specific context for that.

Comment: No wrapping up in jQuery selector syntax?

Comment: @KonradViltersten no need for that which makes this syntax a little better. Value is a property of any input DOM nodes. Could be different in case of a textarea e.g.

Comment: Cool. I agree it's a bit cleaner syntax this way. I'm so used to relying on jQuery that I forget to see the wood for the trees. Is there any disadvantage to your sytax or advatage to jQuery's?